# How slow am I?____________

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way to check in VS 2010 how much time did I spend on particular project? It's just I feel that I'm not working fast enough and seeing the actual time I spent would probably kick me in my ass and maybe I would speed up a bit.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you slow or are you spending time doing other stuff?
Something like [manic time](http://manictime.com/) could help you, and since it tracks the windows by title it can also  track how much time are you spending on a project.

Comment: Well it's hard to say really, because I spend let's say 2 hours every day on C++ (have to study something else aswell) and at the moment I'm working on class LINT which would be able to store any number and have every possible operation implemented but I'm second week on this task and the work it's about half done. (I'm  a second year student)

Answer (score 2):

[VSTime](http://vstime.codeplex.com/) may be of interest to you, it will go beyond time in projects and keep track of time spent debugging, editing, etc.

More details: http://daveswersky.com/2009/11/30/its-alive-vstime/

Answer (score 1):

I created a small application just to track how much time I spend on the various projects at work.

It's really simple - it just asks me what am I doing every half an hour.

It's free, so why not [check it out](http://www.gljakal.com/wayd/)?

Comment: I've downloaded your app. Looking quite nice. Hope it will work as intended. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't track this explicitly, I have looming deadlines and customers/managers breathing down my neck to take care of this task for me.  It's quite convenient ;-)